# ¿Cómo hacer mapeos entre varios marcos de datos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, map

Quiero saber en qué cursos están matriculados mis alumnos:

```
Student Id: 1, name: A
    Course: Biology, Teacher: Mr. D
    Course: History, Teacher: Mrs. P
    Course: Math, Teacher: Mrs. C
```

Ya tengo un perfil de clase de estudiante en `student.py`:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.courses=[]

    def addCourse(self,course_id):
        self.courses.append(course_id)
```

Sé quien son los estudiantes gracias:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    students_df = pandas.read_csv("students.csv")
    marks_df = pandas.read_csv("marks.csv")
    tests_df = pandas.read_csv("tests.csv")
    courses_df = pandas.read_csv("courses.csv")
    students = []

    for _, row in students_df.iterrows():
        students.append(Student(row[0], row[1]))
```

Pero me cuesta mucho saber en qué cursos están registrados. Tengo una dataframe que representa las tareas que los estudiantes tomaron y quien fueron los estudiantes:

```
    test_id  student_id  mark
0         1           1    78
1         2           1    87
2         3           1    95
3         4           1    32
4         5           1    65
5         6           1    78
6         7           1    40
7         1           2    78
8         2           2    87
9         3           2    15
10        6           2    78
11        7           2    40
12        1           3    78
13        2           3    87
14        3           3    95
15        4           3    32
16        5           3    65
17        6           3    78
18        7           3    40
```

Y una otra que muestre todas las pruebas para cada curso en el archivo courses.csv. El archivo tiene tres columnas:

- `id`: la identificación única de la prueba
- `course_id`: el id del curso al que pertenece esta prueba
- `peso`: cuánto vale el examen de la calificación final del estudiante. Por ejemplo,  si una prueba vale 50, eso significa que esta prueba vale 50% de la calificación final para esta curso.

.

```
(backenv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Hatchways\backend-assessment>py main.py
   id  course_id  weight
0   1          1      10
1   2          1      40
2   3          1      50
3   4          2      40
4   5          2      60
5   6          3      90
6   7          3      10
```

Y, finalmente, a quien cursos corresponden los `course_id`.

```
   id     name  teacher
0   1  Biology    Mr. D
1   2  History   Mrs. P
2   3     Math   Mrs. C
```

Entonces **¿Cómo sabes qué estudiantes participan en qué cursos?** Comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para componer la respuesta que necesitas debes reunir información dispersa en diferentes tablas. `pandas.merge()` permite hacer este tipo de cosas, similares a operaciones JOIN en una consulta SQL.

Con esas operaciones es relativamente sencillo juntar las tablas `marks_df` y `tests_df` a través de sus columnas `"test_id"` e `"id"`, para obtener una tabla en la que aparezca cada `student_id` con el `test_id` que realizó, y el `course_id` al que pertenece ese test:

```
marks_tests = pd.merge(marks_df, tests_df, left_on="test_id", right_on="id")
```

Esta tabla-mezcla tendría lo siguiente:

```
    test_id  student_id  mark  id  course_id  weight
0         1           1    78   1          1      10
1         1           2    78   1          1      10
2         1           3    78   1          1      10
3         2           1    87   2          1      40
4         2           2    87   2          1      40
5         2           3    87   2          1      40
6         3           1    95   3          1      50
7         3           2    15   3          1      50
8         3           3    95   3          1      50
9         4           1    32   4          2      40
10        4           3    32   4          2      40
11        5           1    65   5          2      60
12        5           3    65   5          2      60
13        6           1    78   6          3      90
14        6           2    78   6          3      90
15        6           3    78   6          3      90
16        7           1    40   7          3      10
17        7           2    40   7          3      10
18        7           3    40   7          3      10
```

Ahora podemos agrupar las filas de esta tabla en base a su `student_id`, quedarnos con la columna `course_id` y sobre cada grupo aplicar la función `set()`, lo que nos permite obtener la lista de cursos (sus id) en los que participó cada alumno (también por su id). Así:

```
student_courses = marks_tests.groupby(by="course_id")['student_id'].apply(set)
```

El resultado de esta operación es un pandas Series, cuyo índice son los ids de los alumnos y cuyos valores son el conjunto de cursos en que cada alumno participó:

```
course_id
1    {1, 2, 3}
2       {1, 3}
3    {1, 2, 3}
Name: student_id, dtype: object
```

Gracias al uso de `set()` se consigue eliminar las repeticiones de los ids de cursos (que aparecen porque el alumno participó en varios test de un mismo curso).

Esta variable contiene por tanto toda la información que querías, si bien en forma de ids numéricos. Sólo queda convertir esos `ids` en nombres. Para ello haremos uso de las tablas `students_df` y `courses_df`.

Para este paso ya no se me ocurre cómo hacerlo usando operaciones con Pandas, por lo que optaré por convertir estas tablas que acabo de mencionar en diccionarios:

```
students_dict = students_df.set_index("id").to_dict(orient="index")
courses_dict = courses_df.set_index("id").to_dict(orient="index")
```

En `students_dict` hay un diccionario cuyas claves son los `id` de los usuarios y cuyos valores son sus nombres:

```
{1: {'name': 'A'}, 2: {'name': 'B'}, 3: {'name': 'C'}}
```

(los valores de esta tabla me los he inventado, puesto que no la suministras). En `courses_dict` hay otro diccionario cuyas claves son los `id` de los cursos y cuyos valores son el nombre del curso y su profesor:

```
{1: {'name': 'Biology', 'teacher': 'Mr. D'},
 2: {'name': 'History', 'teacher': 'Mrs. P'},
 3: {'name': 'Math', 'teacher': 'Mrs. C'}}
```

Pues ya está todo listo para que el siguiente bucle imprima la información que solicitabas:

```
for student_id, course_ids in student_courses.iteritems():
  print("Student id: {}, name: {name}".format(student_id, **students_dict[student_id]))
  for course_id in course_ids:
    print("  Course: {name}, Teacher: {teacher}".format(**courses_dict[course_id]))
```

---

```
Student id: 1, name: A
  Course: Biology, Teacher: Mr. D
  Course: History, Teacher: Mrs. P
  Course: Math, Teacher: Mrs. C
Student id: 2, name: B
  Course: Biology, Teacher: Mr. D
  Course: Math, Teacher: Mrs. C
Student id: 3, name: C
  Course: Biology, Teacher: Mr. D
  Course: History, Teacher: Mrs. P
  Course: Math, Teacher: Mrs. C
```

No estoy muy satisfecho con esta respuesta, me parece un método bastante retorcido, pero no se me ha ocurrido uno mejor.

Comment: ¿Retorcido por qué? ¿Por la conversión a diccionario? ¿o por tener que utilizar un bucle anidado a la hora de imprimir? Saludos!

Comment: @borjinha Por el bucle, por el diccionario como "traductor".. porque estoy convencido de que ya que toda la información está en diferentes tablas, debería poder resolverse con varios hábiles "join" y "groupby" sin esos trucos de diccionarios, de modo que al final una tabla tenga el resultado buscado. No sé, el código me resulta difícil de leer, y eso es para mi un mal síntoma.

Comment: Cierto! Pero aún así creo que has sacado una buena alternativa al problema planteado, desde mi visión de junior claro. Gracias por la respuesta!