# ¿Cómo hacer un diccionario a partir de múltiples columnas de un marco de datos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero obtener las notas de cada alumno y la calificación general:

```
Student Id: 1, name: A
Total Average: 72.03%
    Course: Biology, Teacher: Mr. D
    Final Grade: 90.10%
    Course: History, Teacher: Mrs. P
    Final Grade: 51.80%
    Course: Math, Teacher: Mrs. C
    Final Grade: 74.20%
```

Para ello tengo varios marcos de datos:

Tengo una dataframe que representa las tareas que los estudiantes tomaron y quien fueron los estudiantes:

```
    test_id  student_id  mark
0         1           1    78
1         2           1    87
2         3           1    95
3         4           1    32
4         5           1    65
5         6           1    78
6         7           1    40
7         1           2    78
8         2           2    87
9         3           2    15
10        6           2    78
11        7           2    40
12        1           3    78
13        2           3    87
14        3           3    95
15        4           3    32
16        5           3    65
17        6           3    78
18        7           3    40
```

Pueden obtenerlo [aquí](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Jx4CPkkLzZOXK4f6SGn03WhYQCeNfe35).

Y una otra que muestre todas las pruebas para cada curso en el archivo tests.csv. El archivo tiene tres columnas:

- `id`: la identificación única de la prueba
- `course_id`: el id del curso al que pertenece esta prueba
- `peso`: cuánto vale el examen de la calificación final del estudiante. Por ejemplo,  si una prueba vale 50, eso significa que esta prueba vale 50% de la calificación final para esta curso.

.

```
(backenv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Hatchways\backend-assessment>py main.py
   id  course_id  weight
0   1          1      10
1   2          1      40
2   3          1      50
3   4          2      40
4   5          2      60
5   6          3      90
6   7          3      10
```

Pueden obtenerlo [aquí](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pIi2hWO3L9ng9PCzzsfg76PD8JwT55N_).

Y, finalmente, a quien cursos corresponden los `course_id`.

```
   id     name  teacher
0   1  Biology    Mr. D
1   2  History   Mrs. P
2   3     Math   Mrs. C
```

Pueden obtenerlo [aquí](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zVSxuIINwoFyDhErYlxk4sQ03LFx7IiQ).

Entonces **¿Cómo sabes qué cualificaciones los estudiantes obtienen ?**

## Mi intento

import pandas

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    students_df = pandas.read_csv("students.csv")
    marks_df = pandas.read_csv("marks.csv")
    tests_df = pandas.read_csv("tests.csv")
    courses_df = pandas.read_csv("courses.csv")

    marks_tests = pandas.merge(marks_df, tests_df, left_on="test_id", right_on="id")
    student_courses = marks_tests.groupby(by="student_id")['course_id'].apply(set)

    students_dict = students_df.set_index("id").to_dict(orient="index")
    courses_dict = courses_df.set_index("id").to_dict(orient="index")

    for student_id, course_ids in student_courses.iteritems():
        print("Student id: {}, name: {name}".format(student_id, **students_dict[student_id]))
        final_grades = []
        for course_id in course_ids:
            marks = marks_tests.loc[(marks_tests['course_id'] == course_id) & (marks_tests['student_id'] == student_id)]
            final_grades.append(sum(marks['mark']*(marks['weight']/100.0)))

        print("Total Average: {0}".format(mean(final_grades)))      
        for course_id in course_ids:
            print("  Course: {name}, Teacher: {teacher}".format(**courses_dict[course_id]))
            marks = marks_tests.loc[(marks_tests['course_id'] == course_id) & (marks_tests['student_id'] == student_id)]
            final_grade = sum(marks['mark']*(marks['weight']/100.0))
            print("  Final Grade: {0}%".format(final_grade))
```

Intenté transformar acceder a los datos del marco de datos. Quasi tengo la solucion pero me parece que hay problemas con pocas calificaciones.

```
(backenv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Hatchways\backend-assessment>py main.py
Student id: 1, name: A
Total Average: 72.03333333333333
  Course: Biology, Teacher: Mr. D
  Final Grade: 90.10000000000001%
  Course: History, Teacher:  Mrs. P
  Final Grade: 51.8%
  Course: Math, Teacher:  Mrs. C
  Final Grade: 74.2%
Student id: 2, name: B
Total Average: 62.150000000000006
  Course: Biology, Teacher: Mr. D
  Final Grade: 50.10000000000001%
  Course: Math, Teacher:  Mrs. C
  Final Grade: 74.2%
Student id: 3, name: C
Total Average: 72.03333333333333
  Course: Biology, Teacher: Mr. D
  Final Grade: 90.10000000000001%
  Course: History, Teacher:  Mrs. P
  Final Grade: 51.8%
  Course: Math, Teacher:  Mrs. C
  Final Grade: 74.2%
```

Comment: El código que pones en esta pregunta es el que yo te di [en otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/251740/7123) (que habías aceptado). A mi me funcionaba con mis datos de prueba, que eran los que habías dado en la pregunta, y los que repites aquí, salvo la tabla `students_df` que no mostraste (y sigues sin mostrar). ¿Qué error o problema te está dando? ¿Puedes poner en algún sitio una copia de tus .csv para que yo pueda probar sobre ellos? (si contienen información confidencial puedes poner unos "falsos" csv pero que muestren el problema)

Comment: Hola @abulafia ! Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Utilisé tu codigo que funciona muy bien y ahora quiero obtener las calificaciones de los alumnos como lo muestro de la misma manera que la que se muestra en la parte superior. Quasi logré ha hacerlo pero tengo problemas de visualización de los dobles.

Comment: Creo que hay un bug en mi respuesta a la otra pregunta, que puede estar causando resultados erróneos. La agrupación debería ser por `student_id` y no por `course_id`, es decir: `student_courses = marks_tests.groupby(by="student_id")['course_id'].apply(set)`

Comment: @abulafia Ha! Estás seguro ? Porque me parece que funcionó bien y con este cambio no parece cambiar el resultado. Las únicas cosas que me vuelven loco ahora son los dígitos dobles con dos decimales y el resultado final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi respuesta original, la única misión de la agrupación de alumnos:

```
student_courses = marks_tests.groupby(by="student_id")["course_id"].apply(set)
```

Era obtener la lista de alumnos y para cada uno de ellos el conjunto de cursos en que aparecía. Por cierto que esa línea estaba mal en mi otra respuesta, pues hacía lo contrario, es decir, obtenía la lista de cursos y para cada curso el conjunto de alumnos que en él aparecían. El bug no afectaba a los resultados porque **casualmente** hay tres alumnos y tres cursos, y el alumno 1 está en los tres cursos, el alumno 2 sólo en los cursos 1 y 3, y el alumno 3 en los tres cursos, de modo que se cumple también que el primer curso tiene a los tres alumnos, el segundo curso sólo a los alumnos 1 y 3 y el tercer curso a los tres alumnos.

Es decir, **casualmente** la información `{1: {1,2,3}, 2: {1,3}, 3: {1,2,3}}` es a la vez el resultado de decir en qué cursos está cada a alumno, y el resultado de decir qué alumnos están en cada curso. Una desafortunada casualidad.

En todo caso, corregido el bug, creo que ya que ahora planteas además el cálculo de la nota final, se puede aprovechar esa agrupación de alumnos para calcular esa nota, en la forma siguiente:

Hacemos que ahora `student_courses` sea el resultado del `groupby()` sin procesar aún en forma alguna:

```
student_courses = marks_tests.groupby(by="student_id")
```

Este resultado es un iterable. Cada vez que iteramos sobre él obtenemos una pareja:

- El primer elemento de la pareja es el `id` de un alumno (por ejemplo, 1)
- El segundo elemento de la pareja es un dataframe con toda la información correspondiente a ese alumno, de la tabla `marks_tests`, por ejemplo, para al alumno 1 saldría:

```
    test_id  student_id  mark  id  course_id  weight
0         1           1    78   1          1      10
3         2           1    87   2          1      40
6         3           1    95   3          1      50
9         4           1    32   4          2      40
11        5           1    65   5          2      60
13        6           1    78   6          3      90
16        7           1    40   7          3      10
```

Sobre esta tabla se puede hacer de nuevo un `groupby()`  por cursos, y a cada agrupación aplicarle una lambda que calcule la nota de ese curso. El resultado de esa agrupación será una `pandas.Series` que tendrá como índice el id de los cursos de ese alumno y como valor la nota final de cada curso.

Este bucle hace eso, e imprime el resultado (haciendo uso de los diccionarios para mapear ids a nombres, que se habrían creado como muestras en la pregunta). El dataframe `rr` que creo dentro de él tendrá como índices los cursos y como valores la nota (según los pesos dados) en cada curso. Haciendo `rr.mean/()` tienes la media de estudiante en todos sus cursos:

```
students_dict = students_df.set_index("id").to_dict(orient="index")
courses_dict = courses_df.set_index("id").to_dict(orient="index")
student_courses = marks_tests.groupby(by="student_id")

for student_id, r in student_courses:
  rr = r.groupby("course_id").apply(lambda d: (d.mark*d.weight/100).sum())
  print("Student id: {}, name: {name}".format(student_id, **students_dict[student_id]))
  print("Total average: {:.2f}".format(rr.mean()))
  for course_id, grade in rr.iteritems():
    print("  Course: {name}, Teacher: {teacher}".format(**courses_dict[course_id]))
    print("  Final grade: {:.2f}%".format(grade))
```

Fíjate en el uso de `{:.2f}` para limitar el resultado a dos decimales. Lo que sale es:

```
Student id: 1, name: A
Total average: 72.03
  Course: Biology, Teacher: Mr. D
  Final grade: 90.10%
  Course: History, Teacher: Mrs. P
  Final grade: 51.80%
  Course: Math, Teacher: Mrs. C
  Final grade: 74.20%
Student id: 2, name: B
Total average: 62.15
  Course: Biology, Teacher: Mr. D
  Final grade: 50.10%
  Course: Math, Teacher: Mrs. C
  Final grade: 74.20%
Student id: 3, name: C
Total average: 72.03
  Course: Biology, Teacher: Mr. D
  Final grade: 90.10%
  Course: History, Teacher: Mrs. P
  Final grade: 51.80%
  Course: Math, Teacher: Mrs. C
  Final grade: 74.20%
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Sin embargo tengo un `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` para `for student_id, r in student_courses:`. Además ¿sabes como hacer el promedio de las notas sin hacer un bucle como lo hago en mi intento?

Comment: @ThePassenger  Quizás olvidaste asignar `student_courses` como indico en esta respuesta, y lo tenías aún como en la respuesta anterior. Para mayor claridad he añadido las inicializaciones necesarias antes del bucle. También he añadido el cálculo del promedio por alumno, que es bastante trivial gracias al datframe `rr` que calculo en cada iteración del bucle.